# Density function obtained from multiple conditioning

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function

Let X follows U(0,1) and Y given X follows bernoulli with success probability x Let Z=X if Y=1 otherwise the experiment is performed until a pair (X,Y) with Y=1 is obtained.Calculate pdf of Z on (0,1)

there are three random variables Y,X and N where N is the number of trials until Y=1 N follows Geo(1/2) but cant use conditioning properly to calculate pdf of z help!

Comment: Let $(X_i,Y_i)$ be the values sampled in trial $i$, where $X_i\sim\mathcal U(0,1), Y_i\sim\mathcal{Bern}(X_i)$. So, you repeat the sampling of these values until the first $Y_i=1$, at which point you assign the value of $Z$ to be that $X_i$, which is a $\mathcal U(0,1)$ distributed random variable, independent of how many trials have taken place (Which will be $N$).   Thus $Z=X_N$ and hence....

Comment: My intuition tells me the solution would be $ Z \sim f \left( z \right) = z $ on $ \left[ 0, 1 \right] $.

Comment: Answer is 2z for z in (0,1) but if Z =X conditioned on N then it is only same as the cdf of X not getting it properly @Graham Kemp

Comment: @Royi I couldnt do it was the answer given but i couldnt calculate it